# Append value of paragraph into textarea

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a simple jquery function to work, but it just won't budge. I have several
`<p id="actor_name">`with various values. Each is inside it's own `<div class=result>`. The goal s to take the value of the clicked `.result` div and append it to a textarea. I can't believe I am heaving trouble getting this to work. I even made a JSFIDDLE to separate it from the rest of my application and it still won't work.

The fiddle is here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JNaS9/).

The code is also below. I just hope it's not something like a missing semi con, so I don't make myself look so bad :/

**html**

```
    <div class="found_actors">
      <div class="result"><p id="actor_name">Actor Name1</p></div>     
      <div class="result"><p id="actor_name">Actor Name2</p></div>     
      <div class="result"><p id="actor_name">Actor Name3</p></div>     
      <div class="result"><p id="actor_name">Actor Name4</p></div>     
      <div class="result"><p id="actor_name">Actor Name5</p></div>     
    </div>

    <textarea readonly="" style="resize: none;" rows="20" cols="20" name="actors"></textarea>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".result").click(function() {
                $("[name='actors']").append($("#actor_name").val());
            });
```

Comment: Ids are meant to be unique.

Comment: I know. A beginners mistake. :/ But anyway, when I change `id` to `class` it still won't work.

Comment: Check out my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the same id on several p tags. I suppose this is what you're asking for:

```
$("[name='actors']").empty().append($(this).find('p').text());
```

Remove `.empty()` if you don't want to clear the textarea on each click.

Comment: yeah, I didn't mean to use id, was supposed to be class as well. But yeah this works great. Does `.find('p')` always return the one that has been clicked?

Comment: @CreamWhippedAirplane It refers to the p tag inside the clicked div (a.k.a. `$(this)`)

Answer (score 0):

Id's are for unique elements, I also think what your looking for is the html of the p element and not the val() i leave you this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JNaS9/16/

```
$(".result").click(function() {
    var text = $(this).find("p").text();
    $("textarea").empty().append(text);
});
```