# How to undo changes to textarea and text input field

Tags: jquery

I am doing a little follow up on my previous question. I just got stuck on another logic. I have a `text input field` and two buttons. `Add` and `Undo`. When I click `add` the value of the `input` gets appended to a `textarea` and another `text input field` which I will later set to hidden.

Now I am trying to implement the `undo` button, but so far I can only find a simple solution to undo the last increment of the fields. I would like to know if there is also any simple way to undo any amount of increments. I guess the best would be to do something like removing all the characters up to the next occurrence of `,` in the `text input` and `/n` in the `textarea`, but I don't even think thats possible.

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/NgaEN/2/) is the current working version on JSFIDDLE, the code is below. Looking forward to your suggestions. Thank you.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="test1">

        <input type="text" class="reset actor_input" name="actor" value="add actors"></input>

        <input type="text" name="actors"></input>

        <div class="found_actors"></div>

        <div id="add" class="button_content">ADD</div>

        <div id="undo" class="button_content">UNDO</div>

        <div class="actors_list"><textarea readonly style="resize: none;" rows="20" cols="20" name="actors-list"></textarea></div>

    </div>
```

**Script**

```
var textarea_before = null;
var input_before = null;

    $("#add").click(function() {
        textarea_before = $("[name='actors-list']").val();
        input_before = $("[name='actors']").val();
        $("[name='actors-list']").append($("[name='actor']").val()+'&#13;&#10;');
        $("[name='actors']").val($("[name='actors']").val() + $("[name='actor']").val()+', ');
    });

    $("#undo").click(function() {

        $("[name='actors-list']").empty().append(textarea_before);
        $("[name='actors']").val(input_before);
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if jquery has a native undo.  You might try to add your own function undo() and call that from $("#undo").click(function(){undo();}.  Text me and I can help you some more if you need.

Comment: But what do I put inside that function? Are you saying there is a way to do something similar to this "removing all the characters up to the next occurrence of `, ` in the text input and `/n` in the textarea" ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914099/append-value-of-paragraph-into-textarea and the saga continues

Comment: I am not sure I understood what you want to do: do you want to remove elements added to the list with the "ADD" button, or characters added manually in the textarea?

Comment: @ManofSnow I don't understand. I already accepted an answer in that thread, what are you suggesting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store all the new actors in an Array and then update the input field and the textarea like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NgaEN/3/)

```
var items = [];

$("#add").click(function() {
    // Push the new actor in the array
    items.push($("[name='actor']").val());
    populate();
});

$("#undo").click(function() {
    if (items.length > 0) {
        // remove last element of the array
        items.splice(-1,1);
        populate();
    }
});

populate = function() {
    $("[name='actors-list']").text('');
    $("[name='actors-list']").append(items.join('&#13;&#10;'));
    $("[name='actors']").val(items.join(','));   
}
```

Comment: **+1** Nice job on beating me to the answer.  Happens *way* too much.

Comment: Ok, first, thank you so much as this is perfect, second, is there any nice guide that teaches these kinds of functions? or is it just that you know the documentation back and forth? Because I would like to be able to come up with this myself, but I just don't see the possibilities when just reading each function separately in the documentation :/

Comment: well, there's nothing fancy here, just some vanilla array manipulation like push and splice. The key thing i guess is to come up with the idea of storing the data in an array. From then on, google is your (and my) friend :-)